# Detecting partial keyboard runs in RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to capture partial keyboard runs in strings (in Javascript); specifically the length of the run when three or more characters.

While I can do this if I know the starting letter – for example, the middle row starting with **a** using `/asd(f(g(h(j(k(l)?)?)?)?)?)/gi`, is there some way I can do this with a single expression that captures any part of that run (without needing a version starting at a, another at s, another at d, etc.)?

Comment: Beware that different keyboards have different layouts (even within the English ecosystem, much less outside it).

Comment: It is probably done without regex, like `if 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'.repeat(2).toUpperCase().includes(text.toUpperCase())` (that is for EN of course).

Comment: Yes @T.J.Crowder, I'm accutely aware of that. I will address it once I have a working mechanism.